# Qualcomm Atheros AR 9287 DISABLED

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, hardware, atheros

I am new to Linux. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Acer Aspire 4752. Ethernet is working BUT when I want to turn on WiFi Linux says ”No WiFi Adapter Found”. Turn on WiFi Button does not work either. Terminal `lshw -c network` command gives following results -  see following：

```
network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface I
product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 01
serial: e4:d5:3d:4a:e3:4b
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver-ath9k driverversion=5.11.0-43-generi firmware=N/A latency-0 link=no multicast%3Dyes wireless=IEEE 802.11 resources: irq:17 memory:f0600000-f060ffff
```

What can I do？
[image: Image of lsmod cmd result][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: There's no pic but that's a good thing! Please don't post screenshots of commands and their results. Always post those as text properly formatted as code.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I added the results of the ”lshc -C network” command manually.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and: `lsmod` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thank You. to show lsmod cmd i will have to post some pics here - rfkill list all shows following results0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
5: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: What happens if you press Fn+F3? Does it change the hard blocked:yes?

Comment: @chili555 if I press fn + f3 airplane mode is enabled respectively disabled.

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi` Does the wireless spring to life? Now does Fn+F3 remove the hard blocked: yes? If it helps, I will propose an answer.

Comment: Result for cmd: sudo modprobe -r  acer -wmi is: modprobe:  invalid option -- 'w' acer wireless LAN Hardblocked: no though BUT i still cant turn on Wifi and fn + f3  enables respectively disables wifi as before.

Comment: It is not: `sudo modprobe -r acer -wmi ` There is no space between acer and -wmi. It is: `sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi` Please try again.

Comment: Ok result is   phy0: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: yes

Comment: Is there any setting for wireless in the BIOS? Is wireless enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Thank You for the,Suggestion. I did not see anything so far but I will doublecheck.

Answer (score 0):

Checking BIOS the only thing I found regarding network was "network boot", which was disabled. I enabled it and went through the earlier but still does not solve the problem. I added 2 pics. The 1st one showing the button to turn on Wifi which is always greyed out. The 2nd makes me wonder- stating no wifi adapter found.